# What is the host-src if it's not specified in docker run -v

Tags: docker

I have a jenkins docker container 
which I am running like

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Now I killed the container and when I ran the same command it's not fetching the data.

Now when I am not specifying the host-src what does it usually ?
Shouldn't it throw an error ?

Answer (score 1):

docker will create the volume under `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`if you not specify the source

you can list your volumes:

```
docker volume ls
```

and see where it is:

```
docker inspect <NAME_FROM_PREVIOUS_COMMAND>
```

output will be something like:

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-07-31T12:06:49Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/802042a3d5bd336a068ad3c349f7f9e9c9c0ddd5e21b550c57bea4b16625cb86/_data",
        "Name": "802042a3d5bd336a068ad3c349f7f9e9c9c0ddd5e21b550c57bea4b16625cb86",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```